# Meteor: ReactiveVar vs ReactiveDict

Tags: javascript, meteor, session-variables

I understand that the difference between using ReactiveVar and Session variables is, at the basic level, a matter of local vs global variables. ReactiveDict is like a local Session object.

But why use ReactiveDict at all if you're already using ReactiveVar? ReactiveDict doesn't seem to have any advantages over ReactiveVar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the main differences between `ReactiveDict`(RD) and `ReactiveVar`(RV):

1. As its name implies, RD offers dictionary-like semantics: `set` takes a key/value pair and it has `delete` and `clear` methods. The bottom line is it lets you cluster reactive data into a single variable. Frankly, this isn't all that interesting in most use cases, but keep reading.
2. RD has an `all` method which returns all of the key/value pairs and registers a reactive dependency on each of them. The main benefit is that if you have a cluster of related reactive data you can fire an `autorun` whenever **any** part of the dictionary changes. To do this with a set of RVs, you'd need to call `get` on each of them.
3. If you pass a name into the RD constructor, it will survive a hot code push. In fact, [Session](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/session) is actually just an RD.

In practice, I've found a few use cases for RDs, but RVs are what you'll likely choose in most situations.

Recommended reading: the `ReactiveDict` [source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js)

Answer (score 0):

"... a general-purpose reactive datatype for use with tracker."

"If you provide a name to its constructor, its contents will be saved across Hot
Code Push client code updates."

source: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict