# When to use ReactiveDict vs ReactiveVar

Tags: meteor

I'm in Meteor and have been using Reactive Var in my project with no issues. In this current example I'm not sure if I need to use a ReactiveDict instead because I'm getting no reactivity with ReactiveVar.

I'm setting the value of the reactiveVar to a mongo query that is resulting in an array of objects.

```
Template.MasterList.onCreated(function () {
  this.teacherList = new ReactiveVar('');
});

Template.MasterList.onRendered(function () {
  var weekNum = Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1);
  var week = 'Week' + weekNum;
  var query1 = {};
  query1[week] = { $in: ['JC', 'JF', 'F']};
  this.teacherList.set(Programs.find({ $and: [{ CampYear: Session.get('GlobalCurrentCampYear') }, query1]}, { sort: { FullName: 1 }}).fetch());
});
```

One object in the array would look like:

```
{ ...
  Students: {
    Week1: {
      Monday: ['Joe', 'Mary']
    }, 
    Week2: {},
    Week3: {}
  }
  ...
}
```

One of the objects in the array may change to something like:

```
{ ...
  Students: {
    Week1: {
      Monday: ['Joe', 'Mary', 'Bill']
    }, 
    Week2: {},
    Week3: {}
  }
  ...
}
```

When a change to one of the objects happens, the reactiveVar doesn't see the change in the array to re-fire the helper. Is a ReactiveDict to be used here instead?

EDIT:

Helper function:

```
saturdayTeacher: function (name) {
  var weekNum = Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1);
  var week = 'Week' + weekNum;
  var teachers = Template.instance().teacherList.get();
  for (var i = 0, len = teachers.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (_.contains(teachers[i].Students[week].Saturday, name)) {
      Meteor.defer(function () {
        i = 0;
      });
      var teacher = teachers[i].FullName.split(' ');
      return teacher[0] + " " + teacher[1].slice(0, 1);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510951/meteor-reactivevar-vs-reactivedict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will help you in a very easy way, is to add an autorun to your onRendered-Function, where you set your ReactiveVar. Because the onRendered-Function is only executed once. When I get it right, you want to listen on changes in the cursor, `Session.get('CurrentWeek')` and `Session.get('GlobalCurrentCampYear')`.

So try this:

```js
Template.MasterList.onRendered(function () {
  var self = this;
  this.autorun(function() {
    var weekNum = Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1);
    var week = 'Week' + weekNum;
    var query1 = {};
    query1[week] = { $in: ['JC', 'JF', 'F']};
    self.teacherList.set(Programs.find({ $and: [{ CampYear: Session.get('GlobalCurrentCampYear') }, query1]}, { sort: { FullName: 1 }}).fetch());
  });
});
```

Than it will be executed all the time the result of the query or the Session-Values change.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But I'm not understanding it. The two Sessions  with Session.get('GlobalCurrentCampYear') and Session.get('CurrentWeek') aren't changing. So it would appear that the autorun would only re-run if those reactive sources changed. So how is the 'this.autorun' re-running if the Sessions aren't changing?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's re-running from the query.

Comment: You're right, it's because the queries are reactive.